# Prevent Key Presses from Leaving Application

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to essentially absorb key presses.

I'm currently using key preview on my main form and have an event handler for a key press that checks if the windows key is pressed. Is there a way to prevent the key press for leaving the application and opening the start menu?

There is an option for specific controls to suppress a key press, is there a way to suppress a key press to Windows?

Comment: If you are just trying to disable the windows key there are easier ways to do this: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/216893

Comment: Google "C# kiosk app" to find out what else you need to worry about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to intercept keyboard events outside your application is with P/Invoke [SetWindowsHookEx](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.setwindowshookex). This will set a global callback to keyboard events agnostic of the focused application.

Answer (score 0):

Several places to start looking:

- [How to disable windows startmenu using vb.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3308163/how-to-disable-windows-startmenu-using-vb-net)
- [Disable Windows Key [Resolved]](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?381250-Disable-Windows-Key-Resolved) - has a reference to `SetWindowsHookEx`
- [Disable CONTROL + ALT + DELETE and Windows(win) Key in Windows 7 using Win32 application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4529577/disable-control-alt-delete-and-windowswin-key-in-windows-7-using-win32-app)